# ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, vps

I know there are lots of posts here about similar issues, but none of them are helping me.

My app is working great on `localhost` after deploying it using `Capistrano/passenger` to  `production mode` on a VPS I'm getting this error.  I haven't changed anything in the code, controllers or routes... so I'm without a clue why I'm getting this error.

Can anyone help me with this???

** EDIT **

Is it possible that this error is happening because I `destroyed` categories with ID 1-8 on the `VPS`.

If I log into `rails console`this is the items in the `category`

```
 Category Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: 9, name: "Beauty & Fragrance",  created_at: "2016-09-30 10:43:54", updated_at: "2016-10-04 16:35:41">, # <Category id: 10, name: "Jewellery", created_at: "2016-10-04 16:36:40",  updated_at: "2016-10-04 16:36:40">, #<Category id: 11, name: "Home Decor",  created_at: "2016-10-04 16:37:13", updated_at: "2016-10-04 16:37:13">, # <Category id: 12, name: "Giftwrap and Cards", created_at: "2016-10-04 16:37:42",  updated_at: "2016-10-04 16:37:42">]>
```

So is it possible that the code in the index is looking for category item with ID from 1 to ....?

** Update **

when I run `Product.where(category_id: [*1..8])` I get `Product Load (0.9ms) SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

So that is most likely not why this error is showing

this is from the `production.log`

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
23:                                         <% if index == 0 %>
24:                                         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >
25:                                 
26:                                                 <%= link_to category_path (category) do %>
27:                                                         <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
28:                                                 <% end %>
29:                                 <div class="caption">
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:26:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_pages_index_html_erb___619502042981659248_47242510413860'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:22:in `each'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:22:in `each_with_index'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:22:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_pages_index_html_erb___619502042981659248_47242510413860'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:20:in `each'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:20:in `block in _app_views_pages_index_html_erb___619502042981659248_47242510413860'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:18:in `each'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:18:in `each_slice'
app/views/pages/index.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_pages_index_html_erb___619502042981659248_47242510413860'
```

Here is the index method from the `pages_controller.rb

```
 def index
   @products = Product.all.order(created_at: :desc).group_by(&:category_id)
    @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg"]
    @random_no = rand(10)
    @random_image = @images[@random_no]
end
```

Here is the `categories_controller.rb`

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end

def show
   @products = @category.products
   @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
   @random_no = rand(5)
   @random_image = @images[@random_no]
end

private
  def set_category
    @category = Category.includes(:products).find(params[:id])
  end

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

Here is the `pages/index.html.erb`

```
<div class="container-fluid">


    <% @products.each_slice(3) do |products_group| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% products_group.each do |category, products| %>

            <% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
                <% if index == 0 %>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

                    <%= link_to category_path (category) do %>
                        <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
                    <% end %>
            <div class="caption">
                <p class="category-name" ><%= product.category.name %></p>
             </div> 
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
            </div> 
        <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

 </div>
```

and here is the `config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 get 'products/search' => 'products#search', as: 'search_products'
 post 'emaillist/subscribe' => 'emaillist#subscribe'
 resources :categories
 resources :labels
 resources :products do
   resources :product_items
 end

 resources :carts 

 resources :orders

 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

 resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]

  root 'pages#index'


 get 'about' => 'pages#about'

 get 'location' => 'pages#location'

 get  'help' => 'pages#help'

end
```

here is the `category`part of the rake routes

```
     categories GET        /categories(.:format)                                   categories#index
                           POST       /categories(.:format)                                   categories#create
              new_category GET        /categories/new(.:format)                              categories#new
             edit_category GET        /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                         categories#edit
                  category GET        /categories/:id(.:format)                              categories#show
                           PATCH      /categories/:id(.:format)                              categories#update
                           PUT        /categories/:id(.:format)                              categories#update
                           DELETE     /categories/:id(.:format)                              categories#destroy
```

As I said before this is working perfectly in the localhost and I'm totally blank about why it's not working the same on the VPS

Comment: Have you migrated the database?

Comment: Yes it happend automaticaly in the Deploy with Capistrano

Comment: i think `<%= link_to category_path (category) do %>` should be `<%= link_to category_path (category.id) do %>`

Comment: ok, @SantoshSharma I tried that on the `localhost` but it gives error there, do you think it would work on the VPS?

Comment: @Slowboy. i am not sure about that.

Comment: I'll check it out after lunch, then I'll deploy again.. I´ll let you know @SantoshSharma

Comment: @SantoshSharma it didn't work when I deployed again, now I get this error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for 9:Fixnum
Did you mean?  i):`  it´s the same error I get in the `localhost:3000` after using `<%= link_to category_path (category.id) do %>`

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It's complaining you're giving it a nil object.

Comment: @eeeeeean Sorry what is possible?  what Santosh suggested? or because I destroyed categories with ID 1-8 on the VPS?

Comment: Because you destroyed the categories. On your VPS console, see if you have any lingering products that don't have corresponding categories. If so, you'll need to clear them out. Product.where(category_id: [*1..8]) will show them.

Comment: Good guess @eeeeeean but when I run `Product.where(category_id: [*1..8]) ` I get `Product Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: It still looks like your have a product that points to a deleted category. My first step would be to rule that out.

Comment: Oh I thought the [ ] ment this relation was empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124947/discussion-between-eeeeeean-and-slowboy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still looks like you have a Product objects with a category_id, but maybe that Category object is gone.

I'd rule that out by looking for a Product that has a nil category. There is definitely a more elegant way to write this, but it looks like you don't have too many objects in your database right now, so this might work:

In your VCS console:

```
Product.all.map { |p| {p.id => p.category} }
```

That will show you the Product's id, if any, and whether it points to a Category or to nil.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, It really helped me.  There was this one product without a category that crashed the App..